# Trouble with Codeigniter Cron Job

Tags: codeigniter, cron

I am haveing trouble with getting a cron job to work with codeigniter

I have used these instructions.
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html
But it is not working

Here is what I have.

```
php /home4/markwolf/public_html/propalert.asia/index.php admin_notifications index
```

But it is not finding the right controller or the method, instead it is going to the "default_controler". Everything else I've tried gets a 404 not found error.

I've been pulling my hair out for two days trying to get this to work so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT

This works:

```
wget -q http://propalert.asia/admin_notifications
```

But the problem with this method is that Codeigniter's method for protecting the script by checking whether it is accessed by cli returns false.

I came across this post at CI's forum describing the same problem.

https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/236475/#1055830

Unfortunately he never got an answer there either.

Comment: why don't you use **wget method** of cron job. you can easily setup it with this command `wget -q http://www.example.com/controller_name/functiona_name`. Try this

Comment: Thanks Raj, that method works but the problem is that I can't protect the script. Codeigniter has a method to protect the script by checking if it is accessed by cli with the wget method it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution:

```
/usr/bin/php-cli -q /home4/markwolf/public_html/propalert.asia/index.php admin_notifications index
```

the key is "php-cli" instead of "php".

But then there is a bug in the CI core that needs to be fixed. You can find the solution to that here:

https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/227672/